# How to change values in raster inside loop

Tags: r, loops, raster

I have aerial images of forests where I need to compute fragmentation index. **I know how to do it for any individual image**, but I **want to use loop** because the is a bunch of them.

```
# required libraries
library(raster)
library(SDMTools)
```

The desired index value is element number 11. But before I extract this value **I need to replace all values to "1"** (from original range 1-100)

```
# Individual raster can be done like this:
x <- raster(forest_cov[1])
x[x > 0] = 1
PatchStat(x)[11]


# I have tried this loop but it is not working
rast<-numeric(41)
for (i in 1:41) {
rast[i] <- PatchStat(raster(forest_cov[i][forest_cov[i] > 0 == 1]))[11]
                }
```

The problem is that **I do not know how to replace all values in raster to 1** (inside code). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `forest_cov` a `RasterStack`? If so, and if you want a binary result, try `result <- forest_cov > 0`. Then `plot(result)`.

Comment: You are just finding which values greater than 0 are 1. Do it in steps like you do it manually.

Comment: No @jbaums. The forest_cov contain the names of individual rasters: forest_cov <- c("Aguirre_et_al_2003","Arnett_2007","Bernardos_et_al_2004","Betts_1998".....etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out why your code isn't returning the expected result, you should probably run chunks of your code from the inside out. For example, does `forest_cov[i] > 0 == 1` return what you expect it to return for raster 1? (I suspect not, since according to your comments, `forest_cov` is a character vector and so the logical comparison of element `i` to 0 is not sensible.) But, if so, does `forest_cov[i][forest_cov[i] > 0 == 1]` return what you expect, and so on.

Here's how I would approach the problem.

Prepare some fake data:

```
# Write out three fake rasters to temp files
writeRaster(stack(replicate(3, raster(matrix(runif(100), nc=10)))), 
            {f <- tempfile()}, bylayer=TRUE, format='ascii')

# Filenames of these fake rasters
rasters <- paste0(f, '_', 1:3, '.asc')
```

Calculate the `frac.dim.index` (i.e. 11th element of `PatchStat` result) of each raster:

```
sapply(rasters, function(x) {
  require(SDMTools)
  PatchStat(raster(x) >= 0.1)[11]
})
```

Alternatively, if all the rasters referred to in your character vector have consistent extent and dimensions, then you can perform the operation on a stack as follows:

```
s <- stack(rasters) >= 0.1
sapply(seq_len(nlayers(s)), function(i) PatchStat(s[[i]])[11])
```